# Configure interceptor to be registered after the open session in view interceptor in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-orm

I'm writing an Inteceptor in a Spring Boot application but this interceptor must be run after the OSIV interceptor, as I understand, it's configured by Spring's `JpaWebConfiguration` class in `JpaBaseConfiguration`.

How can I order my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` extended class to so that my `addInterceptors` method is run after the `JpaWebConfiguration` one?

Comment: Put an `@Order` on it, ordered things execute before non-ordered ones.

Comment: I tried, tried @Order(10), but I have no idea what order the Spring class uses, as it is not explicitly.

Comment: Also tried @AutoConfigureAfter but the Spring class is protected and I can't reference it.

Comment: doh.. This won't work as you want it to run AFTER the `OpenSessionInViewinterceptor`, ordering it will make it run BEFORE that interceptor. The latter is unordered (as I stated).

Comment: Just register it as you normally would. Or instead of relying on the `OpenSessionInViewinterceptor` add the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` to your configuration which will always run before interceptors.